# React-native: Google maps only loads statically

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native

I've been fighting this code for quite some time now. 
I've gotten it to the point where the google map loads, only after using the Android 'multi-tasker'.

The page starts up with a white background: [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EjBf.png)

Then after pressing the button in the bottom right corner, to switch apps, it loads:
[Google Maps loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZmfQ.png)

But, if I drag to go to a different place, I need to do the app switching again before it does that. Some kind of static updating. Not sure why..

This is the second page, and if I go back to the first page of the app, google maps goes back to the white background. I've tried making the google maps page  into the first page, but that doesn't resolve anything either.

The code I'm using right now:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
  import { AppRegistry, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

  const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
  const ASPECT_RATIO    = width / height;
  const LATITUDE        = 37.78825;
  const LONGITUDE       = -122.4324;
  const LATITUDE_DELTA  = 0.0122;
  const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;
  const SPACE           = 0.01;

  class Additional extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
  region: {
    latitude: LATITUDE,
    longitude: LONGITUDE,
    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
    }
   }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    this.setState({
      region: {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        accuracy: position.coords.accuracy
      }
    });
  },
  (error) => alert(error.message),
  {timeout: 10000}
);

    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
    const newRegion = {
    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
    accuracy: position.coords.accuracy
  }
  this.setState({newRegion});
});
}

componentWillUnmount() {
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
}

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <MapView
      style={styles.map}
      region={this.state.region}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      followUserLocation={true}>
    </MapView>
  </View>
 );
 }
 }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
  ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
  ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
  });
  AppRegistry.registerComponent('Additional', () => Additional);

  export default Additional;
```

Does anyone know the answer to making this work like the normal google-maps component as it should?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I've tried this code with a fresh React-Native project, but the exact same thing happens. Anyone got some input? Thanks!

Comment: I'm using 'react-native-maps' version 0.18.3 (current)
And 'React-native' version 0.51 (current). 

I've read that the current react-native-maps version doesn't work well with 0.51, but going back to an earlier version just gives a bunch of errors...

Comment: No one???????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies within react-native-maps.

In // lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapView.java

```
if (!contextHasBug(appContext.getCurrentActivity())) {
   superContext = appContext.getCurrentActivity();
} else if (contextHasBug(superContext)) {
```

Into:

```
if (contextHasBug(superContext)) {
```

And you'll be good to go.